# I don't arrive to do order_by title when i have a conditionnal year in a request

Tags: get-posts, date, post-type

I have a problem with this request with `get_posts`,when I want to order by title with year, order by doesn't work but when I do it without year, the request works.

```
     $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'year' => date( 'Y' )-2,
        'orderby'=> 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',);  

     $myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: You can't pass 'year' as a array element to get_posts() function. https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Yes, it's not write in the codex list argument but it work .... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and is working fine for me

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'project','posts_per_page' => -1,'year' => date('Y') - 2, 'orderby'=> 'title','order' => 'ASC');

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

The thing is as you can see he is only fetching the posts from 2015. If you don't have any posts with the **publish date from 2015** you will get nothing, but if you want to grab all posts **from two years ago until the current year** you have to do the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
      array(
        'after' => date('Y')-2 . ' year ago'
      )
    ),
);
```

See [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) for reference

Comment: Thanks to answer, oh really it's work for you... I was very surprise that is doesn't work.... In my case it's same ... i ever tryed with date_query without success... so i must search in an other way....

Comment: @LaurentJaedong Have you tried with the code above? and do you have posts from the date that you are trying to query?

Comment: Yes i retry too... but i think it's a conflict with a plugin....

Comment: Probably not, can you post your full code and do you have posts with the date that you're trying to query?

Comment: I find the problem, it came to the plugin "Post Types Order" who sort my old post in an other order , when i desactivate this plugin, "order by" work :) Thank you for your help !

Comment: with date_query i can use successfullythis code  :   'code' $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
      array(
        'after' => date('Y')-2
      )
    ),
);  'code'

Answer (score 1):

with date_query i can use successfully this code  :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
      array(
        'after' => date('Y')-2
      )
    ),
);
```

but "after" is a little different
or this code do the same that my first request :

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
      array(
        'year' => date('Y')-2
      )
    ),
);
```